# Music | Connecting Studio Monitors to Computer

Tags: studio

I have 2 studio monitors and a subwoofer that I'd like to connect to my computer. I have a mixer and a usb audio interface. Should I connect my interface to my pc then use the two L and R outputs on the interface as my inputs on the mixer, then use two L and R outputs on my mixer and connect them to my interface and the monitors? Or how should I go about this?

Comment: It rather depends on which part of your signal path needs the mixer.

Comment: Are the monitors and sub active?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use your computer to record, edit, mix, and master? Or do you use your computer as an instrument, sending its audio somewhere else for recording?

I'm assuming the former. Even if you use software instruments, I am guessing you primarily want to use the computer with a DAW in a recording capacity.

Assuming your audio interface only has one or two stereo inputs, you will probably want to have your microphones and instruments connect to the mixer first. The output from the mixer will then go to the audio interface input. The audio interface should have outputs which then connect to your studio monitors and subwoofer.

***However,*** it greatly depends on whether your monitors require an amplifier (passive) or if they have one built-in (active). If the subwoofer is part of the studio monitor pair (like mine), it may be connected *between* the audio interface and monitors. Again, whether it is passive or active is a major consideration.

Assuming that your monitors and sub are active, here is my suggestion for audio connections:

[image: Audio connections]

This assumes that the subwoofer has the requisite outputs designed for monitors. (It takes the output from the interface and provides more outputs for the monitors. It also splits and low-passes the signal and uses that for itself.)

If the monitors and sub are *not active*, you will need to add/purchase appropriate amplifiers and insert them after the interface.